# Foreach loops / data tables

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable

I am having some difficulty with the following code, when i run the code, it goes through the for each no problem, but my results are not what i am wanting, the idea of the code is to show buttons on a win-form based on results from a data table, but when the code runs no buttons are displaying on the form, and one should be appearing as there is one "yes" value

```
private void formconfig1()
    {
        dtresults = SQLMethods.GetUserNames();

        string scrap;
        string production;
        string change;

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow row in dtresults.Rows)
        {

            scrap = dtresults.Rows[i]["btnscrap"].ToString();
            if (scrap.Equals("yes"))
            {
                btnSREntry.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                btnSREntry.Hide();
            }

            production = dtresults.Rows[i]["btnproduction"].ToString();
            if (production.Equals("yes"))
            {
                btnProductionEntry.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                btnProductionEntry.Hide();
            }

            change = dtresults.Rows[i]["btnchange"].ToString();
            if (change.Equals("yes"))
            {
                btnSRChange.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                btnSRChange.Hide();
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Manually incrementing a loop counter in a foreach loop raises alarm bells. You don't need to maintain a loop index when you're using iterators. Use `row` instead of `dtresults.Rows[i]` and get rid of `i` altogether.

Comment: Why do you use `foreach` which gives to the current row when you're using the `DataTable.Rows[indexer]` property anyway?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger and looking at the returned rows?

Comment: this.SuspendLayout();

// Do all the showing/hiding here.

this.ResumeLayout();

Comment: Although not really a problem that will cause your code not to work, your use of a `foreach` loop is not quite correct. There is no need to increment a variable in each iteration. You can replace `dtresults.Rows[i]` with `row` in each case, as each iteration will update it to the current row.

Comment: Did you debug to see the actual values that are being returned?  "Yes" vs. "yes" vs. "yes ".  Also, why are you doing a foreach, and then not using the row variable?  `row["btnscrap"].ToString()`

Comment: Are you sure that the value is spelled 'yes' (lowercase). You are comparing against a string constant in lowercase

Comment: You are showing/hiding the same set of buttons for all rows. This means the last row wins.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data columns are Booleans (and if they're not they probably should be because that's how you're using them), your code should look something like this.

```
bool scrap;
bool production;
bool change;

foreach (DataRow row in dtresults.Rows)
{
    scrap = (bool)row["btnscrap"];
    if (scrap)
    {
        btnSREntry.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        btnSREntry.Hide();
    }

    production = (bool)row["btnproduction"];
    if (production)
    {
        btnProductionEntry.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        btnProductionEntry.Hide();
    }

    change = (bool)row["btnchange"];
    if (change)
    {
        btnSRChange.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        btnSRChange.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your method, but i get the following error "Invalid cast exception"

Comment: @CHRISTOPHERMCCONVILLE what is the data type of your columns? I mentioned in my answer that they probably *should* be Booleans (or bits) since that's how you're using them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `dtresults.Rows[i]["btnscrap"]` is in fact a boolean.
You have to test the boolean instead of the string representation.

```
bool isScrap = (bool)dtresults.Rows[i]["btnscrap"];
if (isScrap )
{
    btnSREntry.Show();
}
else
{
    btnSREntry.Hide();
}
```

But that is just a guest. What are the types of the columns `btnchange`, `btnproduction` and `btnscrap` in your database?

Answer (score 0):

I will change your code in this way

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtresults.Rows)
{
    btnSREntry.Visible = (row["btnscrap"].ToString().ToLower()  == "yes");
    btnProductionEntry.Visible = (row["btnproduction"].ToString().ToLower() == "yes");
    btnSRChange.Visible = (row["btnchange"].ToString().ToLower() == "yes");
}
```

First, I would use the DataRow declared in the foreach loop, second, I would convert the contents of your field to a lower case and third I would use the property Visible instead of the Show/Hide method to facilitate the use of a ternary operator

also an elegant approach could be with the DataRow extension Field

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtresults.Rows)
{
    btnSREntry.Visible = (row.Field<string>("btnscrap").ToLower()  == "yes");
    btnProductionEntry.Visible = (row.Field<string>("btnproduction").ToLower() == "yes");
    btnSRChange.Visible = (row.Field<string>("btnchange").ToLower() == "yes");
}
```

Of course this assumes that your database fields are of text type.
Instead, if they are boolean (bit), then you could simplify the code a lot

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtresults.Rows)
{
    btnSREntry.Visible = row.Field<bool>("btnscrap");
    btnProductionEntry.Visible = row.Field<bool>("btnproduction");
    btnSRChange.Visible = row.Field<bool>("btnchange");
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `? true : false`, the results are the same. No need for a conditional operator here.

Comment: @HansKesting also your comment on the question is really pertinent. The values on last row always decide the visibility of the buttons unless there is some logic not explained in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are looping through indicates that you have more thean one row, if you dont have a true/yes value in every row for a particular column you are just going to end up showing the button for one row then hiding it on the next row.

For example, this will end up with all buttons hidden depending on the order of you results,only the last row dictates the state of your buttons.

```
btnscrap | btnproduction | btnchange

   yes         yes           yes 
   yes         no            yes
   no          no            no <-- the only row that matters
```